# Custom formatters with generics in Play 2.0

Tags: java, generics, data-binding, formatting, playframework-2.0

I want to [register](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/play/data/format/Formatters.html#register%28java.lang.Class,%20play.data.format.Formatters.AnnotationFormatter%29) a custom formatter for handling `Set<Integer>`.

The obvious way:

`Formatters.register(Set<Integer>.class, new AnnotationIntegerSetFormatter());`

results in "Illegal start of expression". What's the right way to do this, or is it not possible?

Comment: You might want to replace one of the tags with Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using `Formatters.register(Set.class, new AnnotationIntegerSetFormatter());`; `parse` can still return `Set<Integer>` and in `print` just cast the `Set` to `Set<Integer>`:

```
public class AnnotationIntegerSetFormatter extends Formatters.AnnotationFormatter<IntegerSet,Set> {
    @Override
    public Set<Integer> parse(IntegerSet annotation, String text, Locale locale) {
        Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        for (String part : text.split(","))
            set.add(Integer.parseInt(part));

        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public String print(IntegerSet annotation, Set value, Locale locale) {
        List<Integer> sorted = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        sorted.addAll((Set<Integer>) value);
        Collections.sort(sorted);

        return join(",", sorted.toArray());
    }

    private static String join(String separator, Object... values) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i] == null)
                continue;

            if (sb.length() > 0)
                sb.append(separator);

            sb.append(values[i].toString());
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

and for completeness, the annotation I used:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface IntegerSet {
    int min() default Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int max() default Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Since this is annotation based, it appears you can register multiple formatters for a `Collection` type and have them distinguished by the annotations.

Answer (score 3):

`Set<Integer>.class` isn't legal Java, as the generic component of the type is erased at compile-time. I think using `Set.class` should work, though this will register your handler for all `Set<T>` types.